# Inherited_resources build resource as role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

As an example:

```
  def create

    resource = build_resource
    resource.assign_attributes(params[resource_instance_name], as: :admin)

    create! do |format|
      format.js {...}
    end

  end
```

The problem with above is that attributes are not being assigned with `as: :admin`, they are being assigned without any check and so this method is not having any effect. Is it the `create!` method? Attributes are being assigned to this resource elsewhere and I can't find out where it is. Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/pull/153. Had to override `as_role` and `role_given?` --

```
def as_role
  { as: current_user.highest_role }
end

def role_given?
  true
end
```

This will then always apply roles to attributes for either the controller it is defined in, or all resources if you inherit from a master resources controller like I do.

Comment: I think it is `as_role` instead of `has_role`

Comment: @herophuong so it is. Thanks. I'll update the answer.